# React - Component styles not updating from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles

I'm currently have an issue where one of my components (**ComponentThree**) styles are not being updated, even though the props that are sent and the styles that are generated are in fact updating correctly.

I'm using the Parent-Child communication technique where I'm exposing a props function which my 2nd component can fire off against. My 3rd component is then ran off the states of the parent which is passed through to it as a prop.

Below is my code (excuse minor coding issues as I've had to rip this out and generalise):

```
class ComponentOne extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      swipePosition: 0,
    };
  }

  handleSwipe(val, animate = false) {
    this.setState({
      swipePosition: val,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="componentOne">

      <ComponentTwo onSwipe={this.handleSwipe.bind(this)} />;

      <ComponentThree swipePosition={this.state.swipePosition} />

    </div>;
  }
}

class ComponentTwo extends React.Component {

  handlePanEnd() {
    this.props.onSwipe(percentage);
  }

  render() {
    return <Hammer onPanEnd={this.handlePanEnd.bind(this)}>
       <li>some content goes here...</li>
    </Hammer>;
  }
}

class ComponentThree extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      styles: {
        rejected: {},
        accepted: {},
      },
    };
  }

  getStyles(swipePosition) {

    // do bunch of stuff i.e. for rejected:
    const rejected = {
      WebkitTransform: 'translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)'
    }

    this.setState({
      styles: {
        rejected,
        accepted,
      },
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.getStyles(this.props.swipePosition);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getStyles(this.props.swipePosition);
  }

  render() {

    return <div className='ComponentThree'>
      <div style={this.state.styles.rejected}></div>
      <div style={this.state.styles.accepted}></div>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: In `componentWillReceiveProps` you aren't passing the incoming `props` (`nextProps`), you're passing the old ones (`this.props`)

Comment: Still nothing :(   

Console logging out in the 3rd component render, i can see the updated state styles i.e. 

`console.log(this.state.styles.rejected);`

Comment: What is `swipePosition` supposed to do/contain? It's not being used in any type of conditional in `getStyles()`. That function will always generate the same state, on both mounting and when new `props` are received. `rejected` is always newly created, and `accepted` will always be undefined.

Comment: I use `swipePosition` to dictate the transform I want to apply i.e. its basically a tinder esque swipe left/right. Depending on the current panning I set transform accordingly - i only put a small section of the  `rejected` one in just so you can see I'm setting an object of styles - `accepted` is essentially same - does that make sense?

Comment: Use  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.getStyles(nextProps.swipePosition);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really simple in the end and was totally a dev fault :) (shamefully embarrassed)

In `getStyles` function I was doing a bunch of calculations - when applying it to the styles I forgot to put `%` in so React simply saw this as invalid style and ignored!

Answer (score 0):

`ComponentThree` would be simpler if you just calculate the styles in render, rather than saving them in state. Currently you're doing bookkeeping on mount and when new props come, but the end result is that you have the styles that you need for when `render` is called. Instead, just calculate them in `render` and most of your code disappears. I suspect that your bug is a silly mistake somewhere, and by refactoring you'll likely end up removing the code causing your bug.